# Why was my question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609259/css-selectors-for-mosaic

I wonder, since when is it that CSS questions are off-topic? Did some users misunderstand my question?

Comment: Question deleted now.

Comment: Well, the tone of this meta-question won't win you any friends here. That said, your main question does not seem that bad. Which is not to say it cannot be improved. Have you tried editing it, making your problem statement clearer and more explicit? Editing would automatically place it in the reopen-review-queue.

Comment: @HugoRune: I like your suggestion to the OP to edit the question. I've taken the liberty to neutralize this one a bit.

Comment: @HugoRune Bad or good, it's not an off-topic. Which is what I claim in the meta-question. Please don't change the subject from 'Is it off-topic' to 'Is it bad'.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Shouldn't "off topic" be only about...off topic?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192086)

Comment: You got off with a *really* bad start by posting invalid html.  You doubled it up by guessing at the proper solution correctly but showing no evidence that you tried it.  SO users tend to be pretty allergic to "do my job for me" questions, the kind that makes it evident that the OP tried nothing at all.  Just don't do that, spend an hour trying to solve the problem yourself, and showing that, and you'll do fine at SO.

Answer (score 8):

The question is a feature request.
It lacks an example of what *you* tried to solve the problem yourself.

Just as the closure reason tells you:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

A different closure reason that is arguably a better fit, would have been:

> **Too broad**
>   There are either *too many possible answers*, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Notice *"too many possible answers"*. There are a a *lot* of ways to answer that question.

Either way, the question has been deleted now.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: @Cerbrus. Not mine, but the question IS NOT a feature request.

Comment: @noober: It doesn't illustrate in any way what you tried. My usual comment on questions like that: _"Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)"_

Comment: @Cerbrus That is a reason to downvote the question, not close it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I know, that this is a good thing to write in your question what you have tried on your own. But it's not always possible, because sometimes you have no idea what to try. And it's not required anyway.

Comment: @Yannis: So, all questions that are a variation of _"How do I make this layout"_ should stay?

Comment: @Cerbrus they are bad fit for the site, but the correct close reason is "too broad"

Comment: Shog9's [answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224098/add-something-about-minimal-effort-questions-to-the-too-broad-close-reason/224104#224104) is very related to this discussion

Comment: @Cerbrus No. That however doesn't change the fact that the close reason picked is BS, or that your quote from the how to ask page does not justify closing the question.

Comment: Okay, maybe the reason it was closed wasn't that accurate. Still, that doesn't mean it should be re-opened.

Comment: @vaultah @cerbrus Cerbrus' variant is too broad, but not mine, because 2 lines of code given by Justus Romijn (`div:nth-child(4n+0), div:nth-child(4n+1)`) couldn't be given at all to a 'too broad' question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Why? That's what I'm trying to understand. It's not a great question, and perhaps it's worthy of downvotes, but I don't see any reason to close it.

Comment: @Yannis: It is of no use to future visitors. If this question _has_ to stay open, we may as well start asking the same question for different variations of layouts.

Comment: @noober it's not only about number of lines of code, but also about number of possible solutions

Comment: @vaultah It IS about number of lines of code, because one cannot answer with just 2 lines of code to a 'too broad question'. If someone did it, it means the question is specified enough and not of that moronic type of questions 'please make this layout for me'. And there are NO other solutions.

Comment: I can't imagine there are more than a handful pure css solutions to the question @vaultah.

Comment: @noober: Aside of those 2 lines, there are "50" different ways to get your desired result. _That_ makes it textbook _too broad_.

Comment: @noober You forgot to mention the HTML engine you are using in the question. That would help narrow it down, as it would - for example - exclude flex answers.

Comment: @Yannis Well, it's Sciter, lol. I'm pretty sure, if I pointed that no one would answer at all, even Rustus who gave me the answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can prove it giving a single one.

Comment: There were already 2 different answers on there using 2 completely different techniques, @noober.

Comment: @Cerbrus They are not different, they are the same answer. The first selector selects the long bars, the second selects the short ones, that's why they are not literally the same (but describes the same solution). It indicates that you didn't read them carefully. You are welcome to give any real alternative answer. Because you claim there are 50 possible answers and it made my question 'too broad'.

Comment: One uses flexbox, the other one doesn't. I don't have to look up a set of options to prove my point. Some users asked for clarification in the comments on there, 2 weeks ago. You didn't respond. You never edited the question since the day it was posted, a month ago. You never took _any_ action on that question since it was closed that day.
Instead of drawing attention to it on Meta, you should've just edited the post a bit, clarified it...

Comment: @Cerbrus Flexboxes didn't change anything. I was wrong when I wrote that my engine not supporting them, I should maybe instead write they are redundant and the answer is a duplicate. Anyway, the answers are equivalent. You have to prove your point because you have claimed something ('there are 50 answers') which I say is wrong. Of course you can take the statement back. Or you can ignore this comment. But if I said something another person said is wrong I'd either agree with him/her or prove the point.

Comment: @Cerbrus Why this is important: because if the question is neither off-topic nor 'too broad', then why it was closed/deleted?

Comment: _because if the question is neither off-topic nor 'too broad'_ - This is your opinion. Looking at the current state of this question and the one on main, that opinion appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @In other words, you have left your original statement and ignored my comment. OK, now I see there's no point in further discussion.

Comment: That we can agree on.

Answer (score 5):

Lets take a look at why exactly it was closed (the yellow text box below the statement):

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>   **must include the desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example." – Paulie_D, easwee, César Bustíos, Cliff Ribaudo, Parker

(emphasis mine)

Your question does not include a desired behaviour, nor a complete example, nor a clear problem statement. While the subject matter of the question is not off topic for SO, the question itself certainly is.

Comment: It does include the desired behavior, presented as the pseudo-graphics. JFYI, the minus above isn't mine.

Comment: How is the question in question one that's "seeking debugging help"?

Comment: @Yannis The question does not include a clear desired behaviour and problem statement. Its basicly just taking random ideas, not something suitable for SO.

Comment: @Magisch You need to define "clear desired behaviour and problem statement" for me. How is it not immediately obvious what the OP is trying to do?

Comment: @Yannis clear desired behaviour is like "I have this and want it to do this, using this method". Tossing ideas hoping someone will do you work for you is not a good question.

Comment: @Magisch The "I have this and want it to do this" part is immediately obvious. The "using this method" part is not as clear, but it's there (pure css). There's also a "what I have tried" part in the last sentence.